# "Workbench has not been created yet" error in eclipse plugin programming

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, workspace

With my eclipse plugin launching, I got `Root exception:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.` error.

And it seems to cause side effect to make some bundle exception error. I don't think my code uses egit module.

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.egit.ui.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.egit.ui.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
```

How can I remove this error? This is the code that accesses the workspace. I found [this article - Debugging a failed Eclipse launch](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t99010.html) saying that it's race condition, but I'm not sure why I have race condition, and if so, how to remove it.

```
public void renameClassRefactor() throws CoreException {
    // get the project information with ResourcesPlugin
    IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    // 1. The name of the project in the workspace

    System.out.println(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().toString());
    java.io.File workspaceDirectory = root.getLocation().toFile();
    System.out.println(workspaceDirectory.toString());
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Referring to [this site](http://waheedtechblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/javalangillegalstateexception-workbench.html), I could add `-clean` parameter in Run Configuration to remove the error message.

[image]

Answer (score 25):

I struggled a lot for “Workbench has not been created yet” the complete day.

But I got the solution by the following steps.-

1. Go to the **Run configuration** -> Remove all the target platform jars.
2. Click on add required bundles.
3. Check the `org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime`, `org.apache.felix.gogo.shell`, `org.eclipse.equinox.console`, `org.eclipse.osgi` and your jar file.
4. The last and important step. Go to **Setting-**> **check** the checkbox of "**Clear the configuration area before launching**".
5. Run the OSGi application now.
6. Enjoy if it works for you as it worked for me.

Thanks